# Fusion Rate and Luminosity in Stellar Model

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, stars, fusion

In astrophysics textbooks one of the differential equations to solve in stellar model is
$$\frac{dL}{dr}=4\pi r^2 \epsilon$$
where $L(r)$ and $\epsilon (r)$ are the luminosity and fusion rate per unit volume at $r$.

My question is why we can assume all energy generated by fusion goes to light? For example, what about the energy carried away by neutrinos? That amount is negligible? I couldn't find information about how much that amount is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ would have to include neutrinos unless the $\epsilon$ term is modified to exclude neutrino losses.

For a star like the Sun, about 2.3% of the fusion energy is lost via neutrinos ([Bahcall 1979](https://archive.org/details/neutrinoastrophy0000bahc/page/79/mode/2up)) and this is accounted for in stellar evolution models.